# decryption of MS office

Tags: c, linux, encryption, cryptography, ms-office

I'm working on decryption of encrypted MS Excel(RC4 encryption with SHA1),password is already known.In vs2010,I've could decrypt it correctly,however,my program hasto work under both Win and linux.And I have no idea to get the encryption key under linux right now,which is something like below under Win:

```
int getEncrypKey(HCRYPTKEY *hKey, int blocknum)
{
    //------------------------H0 = H(salt, password)-----
    BYTE *pbSaltandPwdHash = NULL;
    DWORD dwSaltandPwdLen = 0;

    pbSaltandPwdHash = SHA1_2(psalt, 16, ppwd, strlen(pwd)/2, &dwSaltandPwdLen);
    printf("SHA1 of SaltandPwd:\n");
    for(DWORD i = 0 ; i < dwSaltandPwdLen ; i++) {
    printf("%2.2x ",pbSaltandPwdHash[i]);
    }
    printf("\n");
    //------------------------H0 = H(salt, password)-----

    //------------------------Hfinal = H(H0, block)-----
    HCRYPTHASH hHash1 = 0;

    CryptCreateHash( hCryptProv, CALG_SHA1, 0, 0, &hHash1) ;
    CryptHashData( hHash1, pbSaltandPwdHash, dwSaltandPwdLen, 0) ;
    CryptHashData( hHash1, (unsigned char*)&blocknum, sizeof(blocknum), 0) ;
    //------------------------Hfinal = H(H0, block)-----

    CryptDeriveKey(hCryptProv, CALG_RC4, hHash1, 0x00280000, hKey);

    if(hHash1 != 0) CryptDestroyHash(hHash1);
    if(pbSaltandPwdHash != NULL) free(pbSaltandPwdHash);

    return 0;
}
```

I knew how to get `H0` under linux,but I dont know how to get the `hHash1` and `hKey`.

Comment: 1) How does this differ from your previous question? 2) Which part of porting from MS's crypto API to another crypto API (e.g. OpenSSL) poses a problem for you?

Comment: @CodesInChaos I thought I must have same apis like `CryptCreateHash`,`CryptHashData`..and same struct like `HCRYPTKEY` to decrypt MS encrypted office documents.However,I understand and resolve it now.Thanks for your attention.

Answer (score 1):

This post sounds like it does the same thing: [Implement Windows CryptoAPI CryptDeriveKey Using OpenSSL APIs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4793583/implement-windows-cryptoapi-cryptderivekey-using-openssl-apis)

A more general way of generating hashes in openssl is below:

Before you do anything:

```
#include <ssl/evp.h>

int main(int argc, char argv[]) // or in an "initialise" type function
{
     OpenSSL_add_all_digests()
     ...
}
```

Then to generate the hash (**error checking omitted**):

```
const EVP_MD *digest;
EVP_MD_CTX context;
unsigned char hash[EVP_MAX_MD_SIZE];
unsigned int hash_len;

digest = EVP_get_digestbyname("sha1"); /* choose the hash type here */

EVP_MD_CTX_init(&context);
EVP_DigestInit_ex(&contxt, digest, NULL);
EVP_DigestUpdate(&context, pbSaltandPwdHash, dwSaltandPwdLen);
EVP_DigestUpdate(&context, &blocknum, sizeof(blocknum));
EVP_DigestFinal_ex(&context, hash, &hash_len);
EVP_MD_CTX_cleanup(&context);

/* Now use hash and hash_len as required */
```

Comment: yes,this is almost what i want,getting the decryption key after hashing.So some calls like `RC4_set_key` following get my answer.thx for your answer.